# React native got an error when pod install

Tags: ios, react-native

I got the below error when pod install

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `Anything`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNCPicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, react-native-netinfo, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-splash-screen
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in` report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in` handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:1490:in `find_proxy': relative URI: /Users/mac/Projects/mobile/Bazban/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec (URI::BadURIError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:209:in` block in open_loop'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in` catch'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:165:in` open_uri'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:19:in `block in fetch' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in` titled_section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:11:in `fetch' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:993:in` fetch_external_source'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:972:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in` each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in `block in fetch_external_sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:970:in `fetch_external_sources' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in` analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in` block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in` resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'